# What does these tags mean [if IE 8]?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I bought a template. There are some tags, which I don't understand:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

What are these if-clause and what I have to do with them?
Are they for the browser, and I don't have to do nothing with them, or I have to render them with PHP in someway?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703684/using-ie-conditional-comments-inside-a-stylesheet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user is viewing your site with Internet Explorer 8 (as an example), then your `<html lang="en" class="no-js">` becomes `<html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js">` (this could also be used to point the user to another stylesheet specifically for IE 8 as well).

It was helpful for when you needed to correct a few things on your site that looked terrible for IE 8.

They're no longer supported since IE 10 though.

Regardless, you can just leave it the way it is.

Comment: So I don't have to render them with php to show only one of them, but I leave them as they are, and the browser will choose the rightone?

Comment: Yes. Just leave them and it'll all be fine and dandy.

Answer (score 8):

Those are IE's non-standard [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They allow conditional loading of parts of an HTML page in IE.

They're no longer supported since IE version 10.

---

That particular use is conditionally determining which `<html>` tag to use so that it has a different class based on the browser. This lets you target CSS rules in the document based on that class, which is helpful for legacy support.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

I found this code snippet and says if you are using ie8 or lower the code in comments are excecuted when the user is using ie8 or lower.