# Conditionally include different clientlibs depending on the browser in AEM?

Tags: aem, sightly

Is it possible to conditionally include different clientlibs based on the user agent of the browser?

```
IE
<sly data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"
     data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='a'}"/>

Modern Browsers
<sly data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"
     data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='b'}"/>
```

AEM version: 6.3

If not, what are the other alternatives to achieve the same?

Note: I tried to get this check done in a sling rewriter server side but the problem is, with the dispatcher on, it will only hit AEM for the furst time and cache the html, any subsequent hit will not invoke any server side logic to render it. Hence, it has to be done client side IMO

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to write custom clientlibs templates as described here : https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async.

And then in the WCMUse class you can check user agent and include clientlibs accordingly.

Comment: Using WCMUse/SlingModel will be server side, and that wont be invoked everytime after dispatcher caches it.

Comment: for your information, Slightly is server side templating language.

Comment: JS/CSS should be cached by dispatcher as its not dynamic, why are you even thinking not to cache by dispatcher?!

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question! I never said we are trying to bypass dispatcher cache. The sling rewriter or any sightly / wcmuse code we use will only get invoked while hitting the publisher the first time and any subsequent request will be served via dispatcher cache. It will not invoke the server side differentiating logic we write and hence the solution has to be client based.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you already pointed out correctly, you need asolution that works with the dispatcher cache. So Sightly is not an option.

Then, regarding the fact, that most AEM templates have paragraph systems with multiple possible components to be added to a page on the one hand and AEM clientlibs are build on a template level (and not on page level) you end up with a clientlib holding *lots* of unused JS and CSS most of the time, since you have to cover all the possible options of components used in your page and paragraph system.
With that in mind, clientlibs might not be a good option to be used after all.

Having static CSS and JS files in your AEM repo and referencing them client side based on a JS snippet will do the trick and - in most cases - you will not buy any side effects with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Wrap your clientlibs with conditional comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703767
- Create a Use-Object that check the `User-Agent` header and exposes a method `isIE` that you can use to conditionally include the clientlibs with `data-sly-test`. Alternatively your Use-Object could just return the proper categiers based on user agent so you can have only one clientlib call.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<script module>` and `<script nomodule>` to achieve that. The first one is ignored by older browsers and the second one by the modern ones. Similar to Vue's `Modern Mode`. Check: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode

More likely you would need some back-end to create your custom clientlib template.

Comment: we tried doing this, module and no module approach but its does not work in IE 11. IE 11 loads both the scripts irrespective of the tags
https://auth0.com/blog/angular-8-differential-loading/